# PySpark: Create column with when and contains/isin

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using pyspark on a 2.X Spark version for this.

I have 2 sql dataframes, `df1` and `df2`. `df1` is an union of multiple small dfs with the same header names.

```
df1 = (
    df1_1.union(df1_2)
    .union(df1_3)
    .union(df1_4)
    .union(df1_5)
    .union(df1_6)
    .union(df1_7)
    .distinct()
)
```

`df2` does not have the same header names.

What i'm trying to achieve is to create a new column and to fill it with 2 values depending on a condition. But the condition would be something like `if in the column of df1 you contain an element of an column of df2 then write A else B`

So I tried something like this:

```
df1 = df1.withColumn(
    "new_col",
    when(df1["ColA"].substr(0, 4).contains(df2["ColA_a"]), "A").otherwise(
        "B"
    ),
)
```

Every fields are `string` types.

I tried also using `isin` but the error is the same.

note: `substr(0, 4)` is because in `df1["ColA"]` I only need 4 characters in my field to match `df2["ColA_a"]`.

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o660.select. :
> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) ColA_a#444 missing from
> ColA#438,ColB#439 in operator !Project [Contains(ColA#438, ColA_a#444) AS contains(ColA, ColA_a)#451].;;

The solution I've read on the Internet that I tried:

- Cloning dfs
- Collecting df and create new df (here we lose the performance of spark, and that's very sad)
- Renaming columns to have the same name, or different name. (ambiguous naming ?)

EDIT:
here is some input output as requested

```
df1
+-----+-----+-----+
| Col1| ColA| ColB|
+-----+-----+-----+
|value|3062x|value|
|value|2156x|value|
|value|3059x|value|
|value|3044x|value|
|value|2661x|value|
|value|2400x|value|
|value|1907x|value|
|value|4384x|value|
|value|4427x|value|
|value|2091x|value|
+-----+-----+-----+

df2
+------+------+
|ColA_a|ColB_b|
+------+------+
|  2156| GMVT7|
|  2156| JQL71|
|  2156| JZDSQ|
|  2050| GX8PH|
|  2050| G67CV|
|  2050| JFFF7|
|  2031| GCT5C|
|  2170| JN0LB|
|  2129| J2PRG|
|  2091| G87WT|
+------+------+

output
+-----+-----+-----+-------+
| Col1| ColA| ColB|new_col|
+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|value|3062x|value|     B |
|value|2156x|value|     A |
|value|3059x|value|     B |
|value|3044x|value|     B |
|value|2661x|value|     B |
|value|2400x|value|     B |
|value|1907x|value|     B |
|value|4384x|value|     B |
|value|4427x|value|     B |
|value|2091x|value|     A |
+-----+-----+-----+-------+
```

Comment: Can you provide input data snippet and expected output

Comment: I've updated my post @ShubhamJain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rlike join, to determine if the value exists in other column

```
df1=sqlContext.createDataFrame([
('value',3062,'value'),
('value',2156,'value'),
('value',3059,'value'),
('value',3044,'value'),
('value',2661,'value'),
('value',2400,'value'),
('value',1907,'value'),
('value',4384,'value'),
('value',4427,'value'),
('value',2091,'value')
],schema=['Col1', 'ColA', 'ColB'])

df2 =sqlContext.createDataFrame([
(2156, 'GMVT7'),
(  2156, 'JQL71'),
(  2156, 'JZDSQ'),
(  2050, 'GX8PH'),
(  2050, 'G67CV'),
(  2050, 'JFFF7'),
(  2031, 'GCT5C'),
(  2170, 'JN0LB'),
(  2129, 'J2PRG'),
(  2091, 'G87WT')],schema=['ColA_a','ColB_b'])
#%%

df_join = df1.join(df2.select('ColA_a').distinct(),F.expr("""ColA rlike ColA_a"""),how = 'left')
df_fin = df_join.withColumn("new_col",F.when(F.col('ColA_a').isNull(),'B').otherwise('A'))

df_fin.show()
+-----+----+-----+------+-------+
| Col1|ColA| ColB|ColA_a|new_col|
+-----+----+-----+------+-------+
|value|3062|value|  null|      B|
|value|2156|value|  2156|      A|
|value|3059|value|  null|      B|
|value|3044|value|  null|      B|
|value|2661|value|  null|      B|
|value|2400|value|  null|      B|
|value|1907|value|  null|      B|
|value|4384|value|  null|      B|
|value|4427|value|  null|      B|
|value|2091|value|  2091|      A|
+-----+----+-----+------+-------+
```

If you don't prefer rlike join, you can use the isin() method in your join.

```
df_join = df1.join(df2.select('ColA_a').distinct(),F.col('ColA').isin(F.col('ColA_a')),how = 'left')
df_fin = df_join.withColumn("new_col",F.when(F.col('ColA_a').isNull(),'B').otherwise('A'))
```

The results will be the same